# How to set a background template to a pdf using iText library in android?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I wanna set a background Template(image) in my pdf that generated by iText Library,something like this:

[Click too see the image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/32558367161498963100.jpg)

I tried to use something like the code below:

```
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("./assets/sarbargandroid.pdf");

      PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);

      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

      cb.addTemplate(page, 0.0, 0.0);
```

but it did not work in android because .addtemplate() methode needs some awt library!
and I tried addimage stuff like this:

```
      private void setBackground(Chapter document) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sarbarg);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, stream);
        Image img;
        try {
            img = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

            document.add(img);
            
        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But it did't work correctly because the image does not fit the page and it create a pdf like this:
[Click too see image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-07/40570417250351605250.jpg)

How can I do this correctly? anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your question and that may explain why nobody answers. I'll tell you what's wrong and then maybe you can create a new question.

You say:

> it did not work in android because .addtemplate() methode needs some awt library!

If the `addTemplate()` method needs an AWT library, then you are using iText. When working on Android, you should use iTextG: http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg

You are using `PdfReader` which makes people assume that you want to add a background image to an *existing* document. This would imply that you use `PdfStamper`, yet your code looks like you're using `PdfWriter`. That's a contradiction.

Your `setBackground()` method takes a `Chapter` as parameter to which you add an image. This is counter-intuitive:
 - If you'd want to add a background image **to an existing document**, you'd never use the `Chapter` object.
 - If you'd want to add a background image to every page of **a PDF that is created from scratch**, you'd use a page event.

Another major problem is that you create the image and add it as-is. You didn't scale it to fit the page.

Also: if you add an image in the background of an existing PDF. Parts of that image may be covered by opaque shapes that are present in the original document.

Comment: Thank You @Bruno for your complete answer, it was helpful for me and finally I used PdfStamper for my problem.